# Is there a way to set the default zoom for bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter, bootstrap-4

I bought a bootstrap 4 admin theme but its sizing (fonts, spacing, images) for desktop is to large was the feedback I got from client.

However if I change the zoom to 70% the sizing of all the elements is exactly what I need.

I want to make the 70% zoom  default in the css for desktops  but that only keeps it for my browser on my computer. Is there a css setting or other setting that allow me to do it for all computers.

Since the base theme will get updated by the original auhtor often

I have tried changing the css -  font size, spacing, image sizes on so many CSS elements but surely there should be an easy way to simulate make it 70%.

Comment: If the font sizes are `rem` based then you can simply change it for the `html` tag in CSS. However, scaling down the entire site isn't a fruitful idea. You're sure to run into a lot of problems

Comment: I ran into the same problem, does anyone have any more ideas (especially regarding Bootstrap 5)?

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the css styles of your elements to fit the purpose.

Have a look at the current value and multiply them with 0.7

If the sizing is defined in `rem` you can just change the html sizes for the content to fit as `rem` is aquivalent to the sizes of the html wrapper